# CCMenuItem doesn't register click

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

Here's my code:

```
etc.h:

@interface etc : etc {
    CCMenuItemFont * playButton;
}

- (void) playGame;

-----

etc.m:

//in the init
playButton = [CCMenuItemFont itemWithString:@"Play!" target:self selector:@selector(playGame:)];
[self addChild:playButton];
[playButton setPosition:ccp(290, 25)];
[CCMenuItemFont setFontSize:18];
[CCMenuItemFont setFontName:@"Helvetica"];


and then:

-(void) playGame {
    NSLog(@"test");
    setUp = 0;
    [playButton removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
}
```

It never even triggers the test string logg, however. I'm at a loss of what to do.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to make a CCMenu object first and add the playButton to it using something like

CCMenu *menu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:playButton, nil];

Then add the "menu" as a child to self instead of the playButton.

Ray Wenderlich has a good example here:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/414/cocos2d-buttons-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-create-buttons-in-cocos2d-simple-radio-and-toggle